# Incomplete type is not allowed in swap program

Tags: c

This program is used to swap two strings and I am not using malloc and doing it using functions and it  gives me error that it's incomplete type is not allowed

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void swapping(char s1[],char s2[])
{
int temp=s1;
s1=s2;
s2=temp;
}

int main (void)
{
char st1[30],st2[30];
printf("Enter the first string");
scanf("%s",&st1);
printf("Enter the second string");
scanf("%s",&st2);
printf("The new string after swapping ",swapping(st1,st2));
getch();
}
```

Comment: Moving 30 elements at once?

Comment: Please take some time to study the basics of C or C++.

Comment: @TadrosEbrahim if you're new to programming, maybe try to make the smallest part work first (just read a number and print it). `scanf("%s",&st1);` is wrong, your last printf is wrong and your swapping function is wrong

Comment: not new but new to strings so please don't make fun of me @PeterT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below program does what you want:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void swapping(char s1[],char s2[])
{
char temp[30]; //create an array of char in order to store a string

strcpy(temp,s1);
strcpy(s1,s2);
strcpy(s2,temp); //use strcpy to swap strings
}

int main (void)
{
char st1[30],st2[30];

printf("Enter the first string");
scanf("%s",st1);
printf("Enter the second string");
scanf("%s",st2); //the & is removed from both the scanfs

printf("The first string is %s and the second string is %s \n",st1,st2); //print before swapping 
swapping(st1,st2); //swap strings

printf("The first string is %s and the second string is %s \n",st1,st2); //print after swapping

getch();
return 0;
}
```

You can remove the `printf` which prints `st1` and `st2` before swapping if you do not want it. The `&` is removed because the name of the array decays to a point er to its first element. You also need another `char` array instead of an `int` to swap both the strings.

Answer (score 1):

In this function definition

```
void swapping(char s1[],char s2[])
{
int temp=s1;
s1=s2;
s2=temp;
}
```

variable `s1` has type `char *` while variable `temp` has type `int`. The compiler can not do the initialization of `temp` in declaration

```
int temp=s1;
```

without casting s1 to type int. But if you will add the casting the function has no sense.

Take also into account that arrays have no the assignment operator.

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you could write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swapping( size_t n, char s1[n], char s2[n] )
{
    char tmp[n];

    strcpy( tmp, s1 );
    strcpy( s1, s2 );
    strcpy( s2, tmp );
}   

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[30] = "Hello";
    char s2[30] = "Bye-bye";

    printf( "%s\t%s\n", s1, s2 );

    swapping( 30, s1, s2 );

    printf( "%s\t%s\n", s1, s2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise the function can look like below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swapping( char s1[], char s2[], size_t n )
{
    char *tmp = malloc( n * sizeof( char ) );

    strcpy( tmp, s1 );
    strcpy( s1, s2 );
    strcpy( s2, tmp );

    free( tmp );
}   

int main(void) 
{

    char s1[30] = "Hello";
    char s2[30] = "Bye-bye";

    printf( "%s\t%s\n", s1, s2 );

    swapping( s1, s2, 30 );

    printf( "%s\t%s\n", s1, s2 );


    return 0;
}
```

In the both cases the output is

```
Hello   Bye-bye
Bye-bye Hello
```